# Citrus Payment Gateway integration in Android

Tags: citrus-pay

When I integrate the citrus Payment Gateway I got the Error " com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

How to add SSL certificate in project?

Answer (score 1):

put your certificate in res->raw->your certificate.cer and access this file as
 getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_certificate)

Comment: I already put my certificate in raw folder but, Where I use the getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_certificate)

Because, this error I got from the citrus Payment library

Comment: I have used at a place where volley request queue is constructed means in application class.

Comment: Citrus library not use the application class

Comment: then put at place where you construct requestQueue

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not at android or volley side.
check your url is access certificate or not api side.